# World Bank Data Plotting with Using Pandas DataReader

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, pandas-datareader

I am trying to plot the dataframe that I imported from World Bank using Pandas DataReader. But when I plot it, it shows a weird plot. Year column and x-axis is not displayed correctly. What should I do? Thanks.

[[image: The plot1]

```
from pandas_datareader import wb
import datetime
ind = ['NY.GNP.PCAP.CD']
df = wb.download(indicator=ind, country='CHN', start=2000, end=2021)
df.head()
df.plot()

                NY.GNP.PCAP.CD
country year    
China   2020    10610
        2019    10390
        2018    9600
        2017    8740
        2016    8270
```

Comment: try this:`df.reset_index(inplace=True);ax=df.plot(x='year',y='NY.GNP.PCAP.CD');ax.invert_xaxis()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pandas_datareader import wb
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

import datetime
ind = ['NY.GNP.PCAP.CD']
df = wb.download(indicator=ind, country='CHN', start=2000, end=2021)
```

then you can use pd.plotting.scatter_matrix() like that:

```
pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(df)
plt.show()
```

in output you have histogram chart like that:
[image]